# In a Hilt Instrument Test, can you have two ViewModels for @BindValue?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, instrumented-test

I am having some issues with a instrument test using Hilt.  The problem is that I have to deal with two viewModels, one for the activity and then one for the base class.  Here is what I have:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class TourActivityUat {

    private val context: Context
        get() = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()

    val targetContext: Context = 
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val setupRepoRule = SetupRepoRule(context)

    @get:Rule(order = 2)
    val activityScenarioRule = ActivityScenarioRule<TourActivity>(
        TourActivity.createIntent(
        context
        )
    )

    @Mock
    private val userDataRepo: UserDataRepo = mock()

    private val authTokenRepo: AuthTokenData = mock()
    private val tokenRepo = TokenRepository(cookieJar = ClearableCookieJarTest(context))

    @BindValue
    val viewModel = TourViewModel(
        userDataRepo = userDataRepo,
        scheduler = Schedulers.computation()
    )

    @BindValue
    val userInactivityViewModel = UserInactivityViewModel(
        authTokenData = authTokenRepo,
        scheduler = Schedulers.computation(),
        tokenRepo = tokenRepo
    )

    @Before
    fun setup() {

        val notificationsResponse = NotificationResponse.test(
            messages = 4,
           documents = 0
        )
        whenever(userDataRepo.notifications).doReturn(
            Observable.just(
            notificationsResponse
        ))

        whenever(userDataRepo.relationshipIds).doReturn(Single.just(listOf(1L)))

        whenever(userDataRepo
            .fetchNotifications(any())).doReturn(Completable.complete())

        whenever(userDataRepo.firstName).doReturn(Single.just("Kristy"))

        hiltRule.inject()
        context.saveTourVisitedStatus(false)
    }
    //Tests
}
```

but I can't run any of the tests as I am getting:  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The component was not created. Check that you have added the HiltAndroidRule.`

TourActivity inherits from UserInactivityActivity.  Both have viewModels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have two viewModels in BindView.  We have a class with 3.